# Some ecommerce data not being picked up by GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

We're currently pushing transactions using Standard Ecommerce, and while the majority of our transactions appear in Google Analytics, a few do not. This has been confirmed by comparing what appears in Google Analytics vs the transactions records we have on our end. We tried adding "logging" immediately after the transaction data object was pushed to GTM by immediately sending that same JSON/object to our servers and then just logging that as-is, so that there was something to verify that we at least pushed the data object successfully.

Having just checked the logs after noticing a couple new missing transactions in Google Analytics, we noticed the transaction JSON/object was missing the uniqueEventId property whenever a transaction went missing. It would seem that the property is automatically added by GTM when an event is sent out, but it's unclear what would cause it to not be added.

Here's the data we're currently sending to GTM:

```json
{
  event: "deposit",
  transactionId: <uuid string>,
  transactionTotal: (<cents> / 100),
  user_id: <uuid string>
}
```

we send this to GTM using `window.dataLayer.push`. That's also what we send to our servers to log after the JSON has been pushed to GTM's object. All of the logs show the above JSON with an additional property `uniqueEventId`, except for the transactions that don't appear in GA which all are missing that property in the logs.

Ultimately we just want to address the missing transactions in GA.

Answer (score 0):

Was it a significant difference? If not, you might be able to explain the difference with ad-blockers and the like. They'd prevent the requests from showing up in Google Analytics, reflecting exactly what you're suggesting.